# Back-up solution for the server?

Tags: linux, backup, centos, centos-7

I'm running my website on my own web server. My hardware is a regular PC with 8GB RAM, Intel Core i5 processor and 240GB SSD. I have installed and configured CentOS, Apache, PHP and some other things to run my website successfully.

Everything works perfect but I will lose all my data if something happens to my SSD. Currently I copy www folder and exported DB sql file from the server to another external drive. Every day. But I'm sure it's probably the most unprofessional way to take a backup.

I also thought about writing a script that would copy these files every 10 minutes period to another drive but this option also doesn't seem right. I also heard about "Mirror mode" (I don't know the exact name), two HHDs work together, if something happens to any of them the server still will work. ButI have no idea how to set this up.

So can anyone advice me, what would be a solution to make sure I will not lose any file or DB record? For a low budget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How important is your data? You don't give any info about what this server does, who uses it, who depends on it.

If this server is only for personal use, your method may be enough. If you skip a day or so, you know that you may lose some data, but you can probably overcome that.

If you want more protection, consider copying the backups to a dropbox folder (or another similar service). Then the backup has an extra backup, independent of your server or laptop. Maybe your server only runs a Wordpress site. Then use a Wordpress backup tool and sync that to Dropbox.

Automating things will make a lot easier, so scripting is a good thing. Dropbox and other free sync services probably have linux plugins that you can install to copy backups. Another option is to set your laptop to ftp into your server and sync backups, maybe then copy them to dropbox.

Another option is to create a Git repository, then sync that from your laptop. If you want to use that instead of ftp, you have to setup a git-service on Apache. Not too complicated, maybe a nice challenge. Make sure you add the database backups to the repo, so they're synced automatically. I would add Git in one way or another into your project if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of plain mirroring or plain file duplication... There are cases where a file alteration/erasure can go unnoticed until after the good version has been removed from the backups. In the past the user's fumble-fingers were the main cause, but in 2018 you have to take in account hacking and ransomware. With just plain mirroring you can discover that your backups have been encrypted too, so your backups should go sufficiently in the past to have backups done before (and if possible just before...) the corruption/hacking/ransom happened (a ransom attack is usually more obvious and immediate than other forms of hacking).

A good backup requires off-site copies. This can be done by uploading files to some storage space in the cloud. If your upload bandwidth is not enough, have two backup media, one of them being kept off-site (at your work, for instance) and swap them weekly. In case of fire/burglary you will still have a week-old backup.

Answer (score 0):

"Mirror mode"(aka RAID1) does not replace the creation of backups.
This is an important element in preserving data from loss. But you must create backups anyway.
Don't matter what you'll be used. Self-written script or professional tools.